# Generate many pdf pages with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, yii2

I have a problem to generate many pages (more of 5,000 pages) with PHP. In real, the problem is a time of wait to generate.

I am use the framework YII 2.0 and the widget mPDF, to generate 60 pages the time of wait its from 2mins.. I have to otimize this time, but its necessary generate the pdf (with css to style the doc)..

I understand to generate more of 5,000 pages it will take a while, but i need otimize the maximum this time, the way it is now It is too long.

Anyone know the way to do this? Not necessary need to use YII, if have other way with PHP (library, or some way else).

Code:

```html
        $content = $this->renderPartial('tabela-pdf', [
            'model' => $model,
            'table' => $table, //CONTENT
        ]);

        $header = $this->renderPartial('pdf');

        // setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            // set to use core fonts only
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            // A4 paper format
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            // portrait orientation
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            // stream to browser inline
            'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            // your html content input
            'content' => $content,
            // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
            // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:14px}',
            // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Relatório'],
            'defaultFontSize' => 3,
            'marginLeft' => 10,
            'marginRight' => 10,
            'marginTop' => 30,
            'marginBottom' => 11,
            'marginHeader' => 6,
            'marginFooter' => 6,
            // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => [$header],
                'SetFooter' => ['<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 8px;">FOOTER</p>'],
            ]
        ]);
        $pdfName = 'FILE-_' . date('d-m-Y') . '.pdf';

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_HTML;
        Yii::$app->response->setDownloadHeaders($pdfName, 'application/pdf');

        return $pdf->render();
```

Just a document with a big table (no have identical content)

Comment: show code... not only words...

Comment: We can't optimize your code unless you show it to us. Are you doing this on a web page? Then you should probably put this in some kind of background task. There's also fpdf - dunno if it's faster than mPDF.

Comment: Yes, generating large numbers of pages is going to be slow. If you're generating that much content the chances are that a lot of it is identical, so you should try to find some kind of caching solution so that the system doesn't have to do the same work over and over.

Comment: There will be always actions that they need to be executed in background. So you could store your activity in a db record and with a cron job make the work. When the job is finished, you could receive an email response.